# Authenticating Kubernetes API(NodeJS) client using certificate not successful

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster in google cloud and trying to access it using the [**Kubernetes NodeJS API**](https://github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client), a kubernetes client.

To do so, we need to authenticate with cluster. I tried using just the **[Username and Password](https://github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client#authentication)** method. I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: unable to verify the first certificate] code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

Then I tried the authentication using the [**CAcert, ClientCert and ClientKey**](https://github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client#authentication). I basically hardcoded the keys instead of importing it from the files. I am calling this API from a Lambda function, where I cant store the certs in files. Doing so, I get the below error:

```
[Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line]
```

My intuition is authentication is possible only with keys. But I think I am doing something wrong with the certs. Do I need to create some other certificates out of this or is the method of using the certs is wrong ?

**Answer:**

See the **Robert Bailey's** comment. I was missing the **Base64** thing. Adding that, I could successfully authenticate to the kubernetes cluster and display and deploy new pods, etc.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To do so, we need to authenticate with cluster. I tried using just the
>   Username and Password method. I get the following error:

Looking at the NodeJS client, I don't see a way to provide the cluster CA certificate along with the username and password, so unless you set `strictSSL` to false this error message seems reasonable (your system is saying that it doesn't trust the certificate presented by the server, which is correct because it is a self-signed certificate authority). You may be able to work around this by installing the cluster CA certificate into your system certificate root store, but using a different authentication method (and filing a bug against the NodeJS client) seems preferable.

> Then I tried the authentication using the CAcert, ClientCert and
>   ClientKey. I basically hardcoded the keys instead of importing it from
>   the files.

Did you also try importing files (for comparison)? It looks like this is a parsing error with the way that you are specifying the PEM blocks, and the libraries may do a better job reading the blocks from files instead of inline data.

> My intuition is authentication is possible only with keys. But I think
>   I am doing something wrong with the certs. Do I need to create some
>   other certificates out of this or is the method of using the certs is
>   wrong ?

Authentication should be possible with the username / password or the client keys. The NodeJS library also allows you to point to a `kubeconfig` file, which should allow you to specify the username / password along with the cluster CA certificate so that you can securely connect to the API endpoint if you want to use basic auth credentials.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Bailey. How do you get the client certificates, CA and Client key ? I get those by calling an nodeJS API for container cluster. So from the response JSON, the keys and passwords are sent back in JSON. Now, if I want to store these, I should create a file and store it. Is this is what are you recommending ?

And Since I am calling the kubernetes API from a AWS Lambda, I think using the kubeconfig will be difficult.

Can you suggest any NodeJS API/Client for kubernetes for authenticating and deploying the pods

Comment: If you are running on Google Container Engine, you can extract them from the [MasterAuth field](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters#MasterAuth) in raw API or from inside your `./kube/config` file created after calling `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`.

Comment: The data that you get back in the container engine API in the JSON field is a base64 encoded PEM block. So it might work to do something like `"caCert": Buffer.from(caCert, 'base64')`.

Comment: Ya I am extracting the keys from **MasterAuth field**, I think `"caCert": Buffer.from(caCert, 'base64')` this should work. Will give it a try.

Comment: Awesome!! @Robert Bailey. that worked, the Base64 worked. Thanks man!!

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar can you share the details of how you made it work plz?

Comment: NVM found a solution